how I do sum values of with two identifiers on both rows and columns
enter image description hereI cannot get the desired output as shown here:
A table was comprised of 21 rows and columns.
Country names are under row 1, starting at column C to column T.
Sector names are under row 2 starting at column C to column T.
Under column A, starting from rows 3 to 20 are also country names.
Under column B, starting from rows 3 to 20 are also sector names.
U columns are output. Rows 21 are input.
Aggregate the values for AUS, JPN and GER for sectors C1, and C4, on both sides and rename it "OTH C1-C4". Retain all the other countries and sectors as it is. From a square matrix of 21 rows and 21 columns, the new table will be 15 rows and 15 columns
I tried these codes but it all aggregate the values including those I want to retained:
<import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('data path')
data.columns = ['A', 'B'] + list(data.iloc[0, 2:21]) + ['U']
data.iloc[0, 0:2] = ['Country', 'Sector']

data.iloc[2:21, 0] = data.iloc[2:21, 0] 
data.iloc[2:21, 1] = data.iloc[2:21, 1] 

agg_countries = ['AUS', 'JPN', 'GER']
agg_sectors = ['C1', 'C4']
mask = (data['Country'].isin(agg_countries)) & (data['Sector'].isin(agg_sectors))
aggregated_data = data.loc[mask].groupby(['Country', 'Sector']).sum()

new_row = pd.DataFrame(aggregated_data.sum()).transpose()
new_row.index = ['OTH C1-C4']
new_row['Country'] = 'OTH'
new_row['Sector'] = 'C1-C4'

data = pd.concat([data, new_row])
data = data[~mask]
output_file_path = '/mnt/data/modified_aggregated_data.xlsx'
data.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False>

